# How to log if an environment variable is unset?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

How can I write a shell script that checks for an environment variable and writes to a log file if the variable is unset?

Comment: I am able to echo $var from inside script. Either I check for return string for being null etc.. That looks very cumbersome and hacky..

Comment: also asked in [unix&linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22904/4667)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want a message when it is unset, then:

```
if [ -z "${CHOSEN_ENV_VAR}" ]
then echo "CHOSEN_ENV_VAR was not set but should have been" >> log.file
fi
```

If you simply want the script to stop and report on stderr, then:

```
: ${CHOSEN_ENV_VAR:?'was not set but should have been'}
```

(You can test that in an interactive shell, but the interactive shell won't exit.  Put it in a script and the script is exited.)

Comment: I guess he should omit the (2nd) `:` in your 2nd example, as `:?` refers not only to unset variables, but also checks for NULL variables. Omitting the colon tests only for unset. (Same problem with your first example, just checks for emptiness, not for unset)

Comment: Yes - I have seldom if ever had a need for a set but empty env var; it is usually indicative of a problem.  You can also play tricks with `[ -n "${CHOSEN_ENV_VAR+X}" ]` to detect an unset environment variable.  The notation generates an X if CHOSEN_ENV_VAR is not set.

Answer (score 3):

The command to write to the log is `logger`.
And you test if a variable is set with `test -v`, so in your script you must have the lines:

```
if test ! -v VARNAME; then logger Variable VARNAME is unset; fi
```

**EDIT**: In case you mean with log just an arbitrary log file and not the system log, you can of course replace the logger with echo bla bla > log.file.

Answer (score 1):

`[ -z "$name" ]` checks whether `name` is empty.  To test whether it is unset, use `[ -z "${name+isset}" ]`.

```
check() {
  if [ -z "${name+isset}" ]; then
    echo "name is unset"
  elif [ -z "$name" ]; then
    echo "name is empty"
  else
    echo "name is non-empty"
  fi
}
name=me; check name
name=; check name
unset name; check name
```